# Sagemaker Endpoint Invocation with JumpStart

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a fine-tuned model behind a sagemaker endpoint. As I was following the official tutorial ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/fine-tune-text-to-image-stable-diffusion-models-with-amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart/), I was trying to invoke the endpoint with following code:

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
                                  ContentType='application/x-text', 
                                  Body=encoded_text, 
                                  Accept='application/json',
                                  InferenceComponentName=inf_comp_name
                                  )
```

This returned the following error:

> ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Unknown parameter in input: "InferenceComponentName", must be one of: EndpointName, Body, ContentType, Accept, CustomAttributes, TargetModel, TargetVariant, TargetContainerHostname, InferenceId, EnableExplanations

This suggests that the ínvoke_endpoint´functions doesn't accept ÍnferenceComponentName´as input. Following this, I tried adding the ´InferenceComponentName´ as a custom attribute as follows:

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
                                  ContentType='application/x-text', 
                                  Body=encoded_text, 
                                  Accept='application/json',
                                  CustomAttributes="InferenceComponentName=[NAME]")
```

This yields following error:

> Inference Component Name header is required for endpoints to which you plan to deploy inference components. Please include Inference Component Name header.

Based on this, I would need to add the ÍnferenceComponentName´as input, but when I do that, it throws an error saying it is invalid. What would be a possible solution to this issue? I am querying the endpoint thru a sagemaker notebook with Python 3.10 and boto3 1.28.64.

I tried querying the endpoint as described in the official tutorial. What happened is that querying the endpoint as described in the documentation lead to an error that was caused by passing an invalid argument. Furthermore, when the said argument is omitted from the call, another error gets thrown, which indicated that the said argument is necessary.

Comment: Please update your python SDK to latest in order to include InferenceComponent(ICs). Some of the examples on how to configure ICs can be found here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/reduce-model-deployment-costs-by-50-on-average-using-sagemakers-latest-features/